# What is the correct preposition in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition in the following sentence?

> Rapid convergence in the media and entertainment industries is blurring the line between “who does what.”

Is “between” correct here? Or should it be “in”? Or do you think the sentence needs rewriting?

I think when you use “between,” you have to name two items — “between this and that.”

Comment: you named 2 industries!

Comment: It sounds OK to me: the reference to two or more people is implicit. "in" would definitely be wrong.

Comment: The sentence is not  using the idiom *blurring the line between* correctly.  You are right, you need two things with that idiom, and the sentence does need rewriting.  **who does what** is not a valid complement there. You'd need to say  something like "between news and fantasy" or "between fact and fiction".

Comment: Even if it were perfeclty fine, the quotation marks would completely ruin it. Get rid of those first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the sentence is right because it is about the comparison between two things: the media and the entertainment industry.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is definitely wrong as it stands. But I can't say what it *should* be, because I don't understand what it's trying to say.

You can use *between* in a few ways:

> between *right and wrong*
>   between *two books*
>   between *jobs*
>   between *the lines*

But *who does what* is a singular thing, and *between* doesn't work in conjunction with that phrase.

---

Without completely rewriting the sentence, this is the closest I can get in terms of making it grammatical:

> Rapid convergence in the media (who) and entertainment (what) industries is blurring the line between "who" and "what."

It's also possible to change the preposition from *between* to *in*, and leave everything else the same:

> Rapid convergence in the media and entertainment industries is blurring the line in "who does what."

But while that's also technically grammatical, it makes even less sense to me than the first version. (What does *who does what* refer to, and why is there a line in it that's affected by the convergence of the media and entertainment industries?)

However, it's possible there is more context than the single sentence makes apparent.